# R 3.0.3: Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r

First, some background: I have been able to create an initial data frame a series of text files. These files describe an experiment where 30 subjects performing 6 physical actions were measured in various ways by a Samsung Galaxy smartphone. The seven .txt files are:

> **xtest** - the observation measures of 30% of the experimental subjects;
>   **testsubject** - the subject ID number for this 30%; 
>   **ytest** - the distinct actions performed by this 30%;
>   **xtrain** - the observation measures for the other 70% of the experimenal subjects;
>   **trainsubject** - the subject ID number for this other 70%;
>   **ytrain** - the distinct actions performed by this other 70%;
>   **activities** - a vector of 561 summary statistics derived from the Samsung phone 
>   measurements

From these 7 .txt files, I create a new data frame with 10299 rows and 563 columns. As the code below describes this process requires that I cbind the y, subject, and x files for the test and train groups. I then rbind the test and train groups and provide column names from the activities character vector. Next, I subset this data frame using the grep() function to include only columns that calculate means and standard deviations for my observations (these columns have "mean" and "std" in the their names). At this point, I have a data frame with 10299 rows and 79 columns. I then re-bind the y and subject value columns back to this subsetted data frame (since they are filtered out by my use of the grep function), which returns a data frame with 10299 rows and 81 columns.

```
 ## Read in data files and store in list
setwd("~/Desktop/UCI HAR Dataset/test_train")
test_files <- list.files("~/Desktop/UCI HAR Dataset/test_train")
data_list <- lapply(test_files, read.table, sep = "")

## Extract data files from list and save as data frames or vectors
features_df <- data.frame(data_list[1])
features <- as.character(features_df[,2])
xtest_data <- data.frame(data_list[4])
subject_test_data <- unlist(data_list[2])
ytest_data <- unlist(data_list[6])
subject_train_data <- unlist(data_list[3])
xtrain_data <- data.frame(data_list[5])
ytrain_data <- unlist(data_list[7])

## Create new data frame 
test_data <- cbind(ytest_data, subject_test_data, xtest_data)
train_data <- cbind(ytrain_data, subject_train_data, xtrain_data)
samsung_data <- rbind(test_data, train_data)
names(samsung_data) <- c("activity", "subject", features)

## Create subset of samsung_data data frame
std_data <- samsung_data[,grep("std",colnames(samsung_data))]
mean_data <- samsung_data[,grep("mean",colnames(samsung_data))]
ysubject_data <- data.frame(rbind(cbind(ytest_data, subject_test_data), 
                       cbind(ytrain_data, subject_train_data)))
mean_std_data <- cbind(ysubject_data, mean_data, std_data)

## Subset new data frame
mean_std_data[mean_std_data$subject == 1, mean_std_data$"tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-Y163"]
```

This final step produces the the following error:

```
Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

From doing some searching stackoverflow and google, what I think this is telling me is that the rows now have both negative and positive indices, so can't be subsetted.

I was wondering if anyone had any idea about how to fix this problem. I have thought about trying to re-number the data frame's indices as one possible solution, but I'm not sure I can do this. I have a feeling the problem is more fundamental and must have something to do with the way I subsetted the original data frame and then re-attached the "subject" and "activity" columns. Any tips/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error will have occurred in a specific line (which you do not seem to have provided) and will always mean that you attempted to subset with a vector of indices that included both positive and negative values. The solution is to find where you did that, and to not do that.

Comment: That's what I thought re: the negative and positive indexes. I've now added in the specific line of code that produced the error. Does that final line provide any more insight as to where I went wrong?

Comment: Not exactly; just that `mean_std_data$"tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-Y163"` looks like gibberish to me. What was that supposed to do exactly?

Comment: ...were you just trying to select a single column? Because `"tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-Y163"` is a pretty weird column name, and if you wanted to select it, you'd just pass the string, without the `$` prefix.

Comment: Agree - the columns need to be cleaned. But actually the "BodyGyroJerk-mean" part is meaningful if you know more about the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

What are the values of `mean_std_data$"tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-Y163"`? R is interpreting that as list of columnames (if character) or column indexes (if numeric). If that's the name of the column you want to extract, then

```
mean_std_data[mean_std_data$subject == 1, "tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-Y163"]
```

is sufficient. Although i'm surprised that's the real column name given that you used `read.table`. I would have expected

```
make.names("tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-Y163")
# [1] "tBodyGyroJerk.mean...Y163"
```